# Excel Auto filter removing by itself

Tags: vba, excel

Using Excel 2010 and have an issue that has be stumped.  I have a worksheet (Supplier) that is protected.  I un protect, apply Auto filter, save and then protect.  When I run the below code, the Auto filter is being removed, why?  The filters are on Cell A4: AO4.  This is my code - it pulls data from a SQL SP into range A5:

```
Sheets("Supplier").Visible = True

'Unprotect worksheet
Worksheets("Supplier").Unprotect Password:="xxxxxxxxx"

'=== Code that fetches data from SQL server in to Cell A5 and below.....

Application.Goto Reference:=Worksheets("Supplier").Range("A5")

'protect worksheet
Worksheets("Supplier").Protect Password:="xxxxxxxx", AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
```

I'm using the same code elsewhere and the auto filters are not removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.  I have the below code in Activation code for the supplier worksheet.  I deleted this and it now works:

```
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then Cells.AutoFilter
```